# Xamarin.Forms with custom renderer for Android yields compiler error

Tags: xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.forms, .net-assembly, custom-renderer

After upgrading to Xamarin.Forms 1.2.3 I'm getting the following compiler error related to the definition of a custom renderer:

```
Error CS0012: The type `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsViewGroup' is
defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to
assembly `FormsViewGroup, Version=1.2.3.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null' (CS0012) (XFormsNavigation.Android)
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I guess something went wrong with nuget upgrade. Generally it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, why you have to add a Xamarin.Forms library manually. But here's what to do:

In `packages/Xamarin.Forms.1.2.3.6256-pre4/lib/MonoAndroid10/` (or similar depending on your Xamarin.Forms version) you'll find the library `FormsViewGroup.dll`. Add it to the references of your Android project and it should compile.

Comment: For me linking in just the FormsViewGroup.dll didn't fix the issue I had to manually add references to all the DLL files in that folder before it started working again

Comment: When I add C:\Users\(snip)\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2012\lib\MonoAndroid10.0\FormsViewGroup.dll I get an error that the reference could not be added. This component is already automatically referenced by the build system.